Swift AutoLayout - PKCanvasView contentSize
I am placing PKCanvasView inside a UIImageView. With AutoLayout, I set the size of PKCanvasView to the size of UIImageView. So far everything is working normally. PKCanvasView contentSize is equal to UIImageView's size. However, in cases such as rotating the screen or opening the keyboard, the contentSize of PKCanvasView is not equal to the new size of UIImageView. How do I solve this?


class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    let canvas: PKCanvasView
    private var imageView: UIImageView!

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let image = Asset.example.image
        imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = false
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        canvas.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .yellow, width: 35)
        canvas.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
        canvas.isOpaque = true
        canvas.alpha = 0.5
        canvas.backgroundColor = .clear
        canvas.isScrollEnabled = false
        canvas.becomeFirstResponder()
        canvas.minimumZoomScale = 1
        canvas.maximumZoomScale = 1
        
        canvas.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        imageView.addSubview(canvas)
        view.addSubview(imageView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            
            canvas.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor),
            canvas.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.leadingAnchor),
            canvas.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.trailingAnchor),
            canvas.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.bottomAnchor),
            canvas.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.heightAnchor),
            canvas.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

